# capture first node of its kind

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup

I have the following XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<product_export_response>
  <success>true</success>
   <products>
    <product>
      <product_id>1</product_id>
      <lists>
        <list>
          <product>
            <product_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">1</product_id>
          </product>
        </list>
      </list>       
    </product>
    <product>
      <product_id>2</product_id>
      <lists>
        <list>
          <product>
            <product_id xmlns="API:id_name_store">2</product_id>
          </product>
        </list>
      </list> 
    </product>
  </products>  
</product_export_response>
```

I am looking to capture the first `product_id` node of its kind, the end result should be:

```
1
2
```

What I've attempted:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
for prod in soup.select('product'):
    print('prod:', prod.find('product_id').string)
```

this is returning:

```
1
1
2
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a CSS Selector: `products > product > product_id`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")

for tag in soup.select("products > product > product_id"):
    print(tag.text)
```

Output:

```
1
2
```